# how to read file into string without escaping characters

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following code to read a file into a string, but I want to read it as is, without escaping any characters.

```
for sheet in style_sheet_list:
    with open (DJANGO_ROOT + "/assets/css/" + sheet + ".css", "r") as myfile:
        style_sheets+=myfile.read()
        style_sheets+="\n"
return style_sheets
```

For example, I get:

```
&quot;\f05c&quot;;
```

Instead of:

```
"\f05c";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Python problem; this is django escaping your template variable. Use the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to correct the template output.